# Cannot get property offsetX from SyntheticMouseEvent

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

When i try to access `offsetX` from a SyntheticMouseEvent triggered, Flow throw this error:

> [flow] Cannot get `event.nativeEvent.offsetX` because property `offsetX` is missing in `Event` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowNwBQnaANigGcBBImACCcJAA8Y5ACbDCxMhQA8KEgE9sGzQD5cnOHAD6ACw1zeSALJI5wFPl7A0AazgBeOAAokAN3IYAC44AGVNCjMkGFcbCABXASQAUUC1AAkAFRsAGQARYH8U6xAgvQBKUP8IYDkvAzRSAQhrADpeCABzP3SYNpIUWMC0oLaIGhpkmAANCq4jOBYSOSQoXwrDY2MWGASoEjhVB384UmdXN08cGDNgATbzS2s7BycXd2oAej0uY0pOACgA). (References: [1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowNwBQnaANigGcBBImACCcJAA8Y5ACbDCxMhQA8KEgE9sGzQD5cnOHAD6ACw1zeSALJI5wFPl7A0AazgBeOAAokAN3IYAC44AGVNCjMkGFcbCABXASQAUUC1AAkAFRsAGQARYH8U6xAgvQBKUP8IYDkvAzRSAQhrADpeCABzP3SYNpIUWMC0oLaIGhpkmAANCq4jOBYSOSQoXwrDY2MWGASoEjhVB384UmdXN08cGDNgATbzS2s7BycXd2oAej0uY0pOACgA))

`_handleClick = (event: SyntheticMouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => console.log(event.nativeEvent.offsetX);`

The only 'workaround' i have for now is to type the event as a `MouseEvent`:

`_handleClick = (event: MouseEvent): SyntheticMouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`

But and if i'm not mistaken, Event triggered in a React component are always SyntheticEvent, so my workaround is a `hack`. Do you know a better way to type this ?

[Flow-try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowNwBQnaANigGcBBImACCcJAA8Y5ACbDCxMhQA8KEgE9sGzQD5cnOHAD6ACw1zeSALJI5wFPl7A0AazgBeOAAokAN3IYAC44AGVNCjMkGFcbCABXASQAUUC1AAkAFRsAGQARYH8U6xAgvQBKUP8IYDkvAzRSAQhrADpeCABzP3SYNpIUWMC0oLaIGhpkmAANCq4jOBYSOSQoXwrDY2MWGASoEjhVB384UmdXN08cGDNgATbzS2s7BycXd2oAej0uY0pOACgA) (but this will not be really helpfull as SyntheticMouseEvent is not defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `event.nativeEvent.offsetX`, I would write `(event.nativeEvent: MouseEvent).offsetX` (I cast the native event to `MouseEvent` before accessing to `offsetX`).

Note : `MouseEvent` comes from `dom.js` (that you don't need to import or require), see https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L284

Answer (score -1):

offsetX is not part of SyntheticMouseEvent. See more context here
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7011